# How implement channels with different chats

Tags: django, websocket, chat, django-channels

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aprVr.png)
I have a Django project in which I need to implement a chat, as in the photo. I tried using django channels, but I was able to implement one specific chat.

How to properly implement a chat of this format. Maybe socketio or something like that would be more optimal. Thanks

P.S Is it normal practice to establish multiple connections with ws on the client, thus adding different groups (chats) to the channel layer?